# ListenUDP, a one way street?

Tags: go, udp

When I run this code an incoming UDP packet gets read in, however no packet gets sent back out. Why is this? (I verified this fact with wireshark). I want to be able to communicate two ways over a UDP connection, how do I achieve this with golang?

```
//Node 1

func main() {

    addr := net.UDPAddr{
        Port: 7000,
        IP:   net.ParseIP("127.0.0.1"),
    }
    conn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", &addr)

    defer conn.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for {
        b := make([]byte, 10)
        conn.Read(b)
        fmt.Println(string(b[:]))
        conn.Write([]byte("sending back"))
    }
}

func main() {
    sock, _ := net.Dial("udp", "127.0.0.1:7000")
    buf := make([]byte, 10)

    sock.Write([]byte("first send"))
    sock.Read(buf)
    fmt.Println(string(buf[:]))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember, UDP is connection-less. When you call `conn.Write`, your listener doesn't know where to send the packet. In your server code, you should be using [`UDPConn.ReadFromUDP`](https://godoc.org/net#UDPConn.ReadFromUDP) and [`UDPConn.WriteToUDP`](https://godoc.org/net#UDPConn.WriteToUDP) to obtain and specify the client address, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://godoc.org/net#ListenUDP):

> The returned connection's ReadFrom and WriteTo methods can be used to receive and send UDP packets with per-packet addressing.

Your modified Node 1 loop could then look something like the following:

```
for {
        b := make([]byte, 10)
        n, clientAddr, _ := conn.ReadFromUDP(b) // TODO: error check
        fmt.Println(string(b[:n]))
        conn.WriteToUDP([]byte("sending back"), clientAddr)
}
```